# DB2 GENERATED IDENTITY HIBERNATE

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, db2, identity, generated

I am using `DB2 GENERATED IDENTITY` to auto-increment value for a column. The column is not a **primary key** column. I am not sure how to configure the field in the hibernate mapping class. 
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the @Generated annotation, and make sure to mark the property as non insertable, adn non updatable, as explained in the [Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#mapping-generated).

Note that this will force Hibernate to issue an additional select query after each insert and update query.